# using svn only for a property not for entire directory

Tags: svn, properties, directory

hi i want to use svn commands only for property of a directory not for the whole

directory .

e.g. svn revert

please tell me what command is used for this purpose.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

By default revert will not revert recursively unless you add -R, i.e.

```
svn revert .
```

will do - that will revert property changes on the current directory but not touch file modifications, file adds, directory adds etc. However if you want to be unambiguous you can explicitly deny recursion with

```
svn revert --depth=empty .
```

assuming you're using 1.5 or later.

If you're still not sure you should take a copy of your working copy and then experiment away!